# Can't create a public static final String in java

Tags: java, string, static, public, final

This code:

```
public class CommandPrompt {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    public static final String prompt = System.getProperty("user.name")+">";
      System.out.println(prompt);
    }
  }
```

Returns this error message:

```
CommandPrompt.java:5: error: illegal start of expression
public static final String prompt = System.getProperty("user.name")+">";
^
CommandPrompt.java:5: error: illegal start of expression
public static final String prompt = System.getProperty("user.name")+">";
       ^
CommandPrompt.java:5: error: ';' expected
public static final String prompt = System.getProperty("user.name")+">";
             ^
3 errors
```

I have seen `public static final String` been used before, why can't I use it here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Explanation**

You can't use `public` and `static` inside a method.
Both are reserved for class attributes: `public` is an *access modifier* and `static` declares a *class scoped* variable.

**Correction**

```
public class CommandPrompt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      final String prompt = System.getProperty("user.name")+">";
      System.out.println(prompt);
    }
}
```

or

```
public class CommandPrompt {
    public static final String prompt = System.getProperty("user.name")+">";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(prompt);
    }
}
```

**Related question**

- [How do I declare a static variable inside the main method ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378758/how-do-i-declare-a-static-variable-inside-the-main-method)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare variables as `public` or `static` within a method. Either remove them or move it out of the method block to turn it into a `field`

Answer (score 1):

Static variables cannot be declared in a method.

It should be delcared in the class level.

Please try

```
public class CommandPrompt {

public static  String prompt;

public static void main(String[] args) {

prompt=System.getProperty("user.name")+">";

System.out.println(prompt);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you can only create class level variable inside your class, you don't say, but outside of a method :)

```
public class CommandPrompt {
 public static final String prompt = System.getProperty("user.name")+">";
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(prompt);
 }
}
```

Something like that should work.[See this tutorial for more information](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm)

Comment: *class-level* (*static*) and *instance-level* (*non-static*)