# Error when declaring & initializing string as static in java

Tags: java, string, exception

I'm trying to declare and initialize local *String* variable as static , but there is a compilation error showing **Illegal modifier static**. Why is it so?

Here is my code:

```
public class StringInstance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    static String s = "a";

    if(s instanceof String){
        System.out.println("Yes it is");
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: `static` only applies to class members. You can't declare a `static` variable inside a method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378758/how-do-i-declare-a-static-variable-inside-the-main-method

Comment: @faizalvasaya as the error indicates we cannot have static field in the methods. That doesn't make sense. You need to remove the static modifier.

Comment: `static` means class-level. You have to declare them at the class level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String you are declaring will be static because it's scope is static, so you don't need the `static` modifier. But if you want to declare it static outside the scope of `main()` then do it like this:

```
public class StringInstance {
  static String s = "a";
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    if(s instanceof String){
        System.out.println("Yes it is");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My doubt is that , since main being a static block , it should be possible to declare as static inside it.

Comment: @faizalvasaya It is already static without the explicit `static` modifier because it is inside a static scope.

Comment: Thank you @Jonah Haney ! You clarified my doubt.